# How to update device admin application from Play Store?

Tags: android, admin, device, google-play-services

I have an android application which uses `device admin api` and it is published in `Google Play Store`.Now i have a doubt that When we release new version of this application, whether it is easily upgraded, like any other applications.I could not found an  information.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: ok....I will edit my question...

Comment: Yes, that will be updated like normal applications. don't worry about that..

Comment: Are you sure?Is there any documents related to this?

Comment: :D I am sure I am an MDM developer and I used Device Admin API in more than two applications, and they are working fine. :)

Comment: But I have no documents to provide you..

Comment: Asha did you have success rolling out an update to your Device Admin app? @Pankaj I assume that Asha's concerns came from the fact that you cannot uninstall an app that is currently a Device Admin, leading him (and me) to believe that the Google Play update process may have problems too

Comment: @PankajKumar i cannot update a device admin via Play Store. It gets stuck on update loading on Play store

Comment: @Thracian Any error you are getting? Check if all policies enforced by your app is correct and not being the cause of it.